# Original Enterprise photon torpedo complement

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In Star Trek, The Original Series, what is the maximum number of photon torpedoes that the Enterprise NCC-1701 can hold?

Comment: The photon torpedoes on the Enterprise NCC-1701 were really nice.

Comment: Is that a photon torpedo you're carrying, or are you just happy to see me?

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was reasonably comprehensive, featuring an in-universe quote from one of the few factbooks to address the original Enterprise. Is there anything else you think I should add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Using a [ship volume](http://www.st-v-sw.net/STSWvolumetrics.html) of 211,248m³ and [torpedo dimensions](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/lcars24/lcars24-sheet-32.jpg) of 2.1m x 0.76m x 0.45m — and with transporters to make efficient use of storage space — we get an upper limit of 294,135 torpedoes.  Reduce that number by an order of magnitude or so because of bulkheads and equipment, and the ship can still carry about 30,000.  Not what you meant, of course, but handy if another [planet killer](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_killer) shows up.

Answer (score 8):

According to the semi-canon [**Mr Scott's Guide to the Enterprise**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Scott%27s_Guide_to_the_Enterprise), the *"photorp"* complement of the NCC-1701 Enterprise is **20 x Morris Magtronic FP-4 photonic torpedoes.**

Since Mr Scott doesn't explain that this has *changed post-refit*, we can reasonably assume that it also applies to the original NCC-1701 as well as the refit version seen in the film series.

[image: rt]

Comment: The image could use a highlight to the part that addresses the question

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Your merest whim is my most heartfelt desire.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not sure this answers the question.  It was asked about the TOS Enterprise.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - This answer relates to the NCC-1701 (TOS) Enterprise. The complement doesn't appear to have been changed post-refit

Comment: None of the "technical details" on that page appears to have any relation to what we saw on the show. They appear to have been made up out of whole cloth.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - That is as maybe. The book was, however, consulted upon by the same people who made up the *facts* seen on the show.

Comment: @Valorum - Check your link again, the front cover clearly shows the refit Enterprise.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - And while that's true, the book highlights the differences between the original Enterprise and the refit Enterprise. Where it gives a fact (without explaining the difference) we can assume that it applies **to both**.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question Valorum.  So just to clarify, the maximum payload was twenty photon torpedoes?  That seems a bit small.

Comment: @mrvankil - The Enterprise isn't a ship of war, it's a ship of exploration that happens to be quite heavily armed. I would assume that they can store more in the cargo bays if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Most deck plans that I have seen indicates 40 photorps. The magazines are on decks 10 and 11 which is located in the Dorsal (neck) section. They are divided into two racks on each deck (four total) with each rack holding 10 photorps(total of 40).

Comment: This answer would be stronger if you linked to at least one deck plan that indicates 40 photon torpedoes and explained why it should be considered canon.  Even stronger would rely on quotations from one or more episodes that support this.

Comment: Note also that most deck plans are fan-created.